# What Voice effects are used in Solomun - See You Everyday Alone?

Tags: effects, music

What effect(s) is(are) used on the male voice in the song by Solomun "See You Everyday Alone (original mix)"? Is it a layer of effects? Towards the end the effect is much less and I can actually understand the voice, but in the rest of the song the voice is hard to understand, and has a deep, dark, and sexy vibe to it. Is it running through a vocoder?

Here are some different links to preview the songs.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/challenge-everyday-ep/id461419358

http://open.spotify.com/album/3hk3Nvql64R1OZGNkdkoPJ

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the same effect (audible at 4:30), this does not sound like a vocoder (although it resembles it slightly).

What I can hear is pitch shifting (so possibly a sort of harmoniser is involved), there is also some modulation of a filter of a sort with rather clear comb-effect or phase-effect. This modulation does not seem periodic, but rather correlated to his singing. There is also some distortion involved, which may also be the process in charge of the overall filtering of the timbre.

I'm not aware of a multi-effect unit that offers this exact preset, but [SoundToys](https://www.soundtoys.com/product/) plugins, primarily Crystallizer, 
PhaseMistress and FilterFreak (and the possible combination of which) should get you pretty close.